# C++ Class mask and heritage

Tags: c++, class

I'm back with a stupid question.. :)

In C++, I would like to do the following:

```
class dataproject : public data
{
    public:
        dataproject();
        ~dataproject();

        virtual wxString GetComment(void);

    private:
        wxString m_comment;
};

class listproject : public listdata
{
    public:
        listproject();
        ~listproject();
        bool Load();       
};

(one of the function of listproject)
{
    dataproject data;
    data.SetComment("blablabla");
    m_list.push_front(data);    
}

class dataclient : public data
{
    public:
        dataclient();
        ~dataclient();
};

class listclient  : public listdata
{
    public:
        listclient();
        ~listclient();
        bool Load();
};

class data
{
    public:
        data();
        virtual ~data();
        wxString GetName(void);

    protected:
        wxString  m_name;
};


class listdata
{
    public:
        data * GetById(unsigned int id);

    protected:
        std::list<data> m_list;
};
```

Means, I have two class containing the data, then two class to load the list for each and one mother class to list the data of the list class.

My explanation is quite crape but I don't know how to explain it...

If I call `GetName`, no problem I get my data.
If I call `GetComment`, the program crashes. I've tried to do something like:

```
dataproject * listproject::GetById(unsigned int id)
{
    return  (dataproject*) listdata::GetById(id);
}
```

But it also crashes.

I do believe there is a way to do what I want, access the function of a child class.

**Edit:
To try to be more clear, I store on a list heterogeneous data which are two child class linked to a mother class. When i get back to one entry of my list, I would like to be able to access to the function located on the child class.**

```
class child A : Mother
class child B : Mother
class Mother

list<Mother> datalist

datalist->function_of_child_B
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question!  Perhaps you could post a complete compilable example that demonstrates the issue?  (see http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Your classes `listclient` and `listproject` are identical except for the name and your class `dataclient` seems useless. Is that really what you want?

Comment: I've truncate the code as it's too long to be posted here. It's obvious my question is not clear, I will try to reformat it

Comment: Seriously, you should work on your question. The explanations of the code don't make much sense, and adding different bits of code *out of order* does not help either, as it makes it much harder to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `list<Mother>` you must use `list<Mother*>`. When you use `list<Mother>` then item in the list must be just `Mother`, and nothing else besides `Mother`, because `list<>` makes enough room only for `Mother` object (`sizeof(Mother)`). If you try to "cram" in object derived from `Mother` `list<>` will clip that object, effectively making it `Mother`, but with virtual table of orginal object, which is undefined behavior. When you use `list<Mother*>` then you can have any object derived from `Mother` because `list<>` makes room only for pointer (`sizeof(Mother*)`), and size of a pointer is the same for all classes.

Comment: Yes, actually using pointer do not "destroy the structure". then possible to set the class back.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** do that

```
class child A : Mother
class child B : Mother
class Mother

list<Mother> datalist

datalist->function_of_child_B
```

If I understand your question, in order to do what you want you need virtual functions

```
class Mother{
public:
   Mother();
   virtual function1() = 0; // It could be pure virtual
   virtual function2() {std::cout << "Mother Function 2";}     // or just virtual
}

class A : public Mother {
public:
   function1() {std::cout << "A function 1";}
   function2() {std::cout << "A function 2";}
}

class B : public Mother {
public:
   function1() {std::cout << "B function 1";}
}
```

Now create objects of A, B

```
A* a = new A;
B* b = new B;

// Add them to a vector of Mother* (or list if you prefer it)
std::vector<Mother*> v;
v.push_back((Mother*)a);
v.push_back((Mother*)b);

v[0]->function1(); // prints A function 1
v[0]->function2(); // prints A function 2
v[1]->function1(); // prints B function 1
v[1]->function2(); // prints Mother function 2
```

Now assume that class A has a function called `functionA()` and B has a function called `functionB()` and you want to call one of these two in a member `v[i]` of your `Mother*` vector. In these case you could use `dynamic_cast` in order to execute a function present only in a subclass of your `Mother` class

```
A* pA = dynamic_cast<A*>(v[i]);
if (pA != NULL)
    pA->functionA();
B* pB = dynamic_cast<B*>(v[i]);
if (pB != NULL)
    pB->functionB();
```